# setting keyframs doesn't work

Tags: animation, keyframes

good day
(using v3.4.1)
When I try to set a key frame with "I" and choose "insert keyframes" - "only selected channels" or "all channels" it want set a keyframe....
Weird thing is, this only happens in between the frames. When I am at the end and wanna do this it works.
I made a YT video, I hope it makes sense.
https://youtu.be/mb5yscGgleI

Thank you very much
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your animation preferences, probably you have activated "Only insert needed" function, so when you try to add a keyframe on an horizontal curve it detects that it isn't useful and rejects the input.

You can either disable this preference or (as I usually do) select a keyframe and use Shift D (duplicate) to create a new keframe, which it's possible to move and edit as needed.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much!!!!! This is it! I did as a workaround use shit + d as you said.
Now I know more.